# How to insert multiple rows based on one list of ids dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my html form where I have an array of dynamic fields. In other words, Fields can be generated dynamically.

```
<form>
 |Product
 <input type="text" name="Product[Name][]">  
 <input type="text" name="Product[Number][]">  
  <input type="text" name="Product[Description][]"> 

 |Product Accessories
 <input type="text" name="Accessory[Name][]">  
 <input type="text" name="Accessory[Number][]">  
  <input type="text" name="Accessory[Description][]"> 
</form>
```

This is my PHP getting the values from HTML arrays.

```
 <?php
 $product = $_POST['Product'];
 $accessory = $_POST['Accessory'];

 if ($this->hasValueAndNotEmpty($product)) {
   foreach($product as $key=>$productItem)
   {
      //Issue: How do I use the product id to insert accessories
      /*Maybe like this..*/
     foreach($accessory as $$accessoryItem){

     } 


   } 
}
```

Database scheme goes as follow:

**`Product`** Table

```
  id 
  name 
  number 
  description
.....
```

**`Product_Accessories`** Table

```
   id
   product_id
   name
   number
```

My goal is to insert into the `Product_Accessories` table all the accessories matching the `product_id` that they belong to.

In sudo code will be:

1. User specified 2 products
2. Those 2 products have 4 accessories (2 each)
3. Before inserting accessories check if there was actually any
   specified.
4. Insert accessories matching products specified in the HTML form.

   The following code works in terms of what I want to accomplish however I'm not sure how to pull the accessories field value.

   ```
    $fields = array_combine(array_keys($product_fields),
     array_values($product_fields));
     $product (model) after inserting first.


       foreach($product as $key => $productItem) {

      if ($this->hasValue($fields)) {


          for ($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++) {

          }


          var_dump($productItem->accessory()->create([

              'name' => 'kllk',
              'number' => 'fddfl',
              'description' => 'dfldfkl',
          ]));

      }

    }
   ```

   When I go and check the accessories table, it does insert the accessories with the corresponding product_id however don't know how to insert the actually accessories field values.

Comment: You can't differentiate which accessories belong to which product as your name doesn't differentiate it either. There are two possible options: 1) Using AJAX request in the frontend. You can use `data-attributes` to differentiate between the product accessories. Second one is not a clean solution but you can add a hidden field to `Product Form` generating a unique id of some sort, and when new product accessories are added to the product, make sure they have the same hidden field as well with the same value. Then in PHP you can insert all the products first.

Comment: @kks21199 Correct I agree with what you are saying in terms of inserting the products first. The accessories i know which one below to which product because on the html form if only one product is generated, it has the option to include an accessory or not. If they do I know that accessories belongs to product one after checking if accessories were specified. I was able to accomplished what I wanted using 2 nested loops however i was unable to pull the actual values of the accessories fields but was able to insert the accessories belonging to specified products.

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions that you can use.

1) Use AJAX along with data-attributes to differentiate which accessory belongs to which item.

2) Include a hidden text field in your product that has a unique id. When new accessory fields is created make sure they have the same unique id as well.

```
<form>
 |Product
 <input type="text" name="Product[Name][]">  
 <input type="text" name="Product[Number][]">  
 <input type="text" name="Product[Description][]"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="Product[uuid][]" value="12345"> <!-- this should be generated --> 

 |Product Accessories
 <input type="text" name="Accessory[Name][]">  
 <input type="text" name="Accessory[Number][]">  
 <input type="text" name="Accessory[Description][]"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="Accessory[uuid][]" value = "12345"> <!-- this should be copied from the product which the accessory belongs to -->  
</form>
```

Then in php you can first insert all the products and then create a array that points which `uuid` belongs to which `id` in the database.

If the product above was inserted into the database with id 2,

`$uuid_id = [ '12345' => 2 ];`

Then use a foreach loop for your `Accessory Array` , and load product id by using the uuid value. `$product_id = $uuid_id[ UUID ];`

For the UUID use the current time so it's always unique.

```
 new Date().getTime(); //for JavaScript
```

or

```
microtime(true); //for php
```

Comment: @AlexGarcia can you share your current code that works for you partially?

Comment: @ kks21199 I added the code that work above however not sure how to insert the accessories fields values entered.